# Incorrect output of prometheus metrics

Tags: parachain, parachain-collator, prometheus, metrics

has anyone come across the fact that prometheus metrics from the collator and embedded relay chain return the official name - rococo_local_testnet, although the collator name in chainspec is local_testnet. Also, metrics that should return block numbers (substrate_block_height) return them only for the relay chain
What could be the problem?
I can also provide metrics files or screenshots if that makes sense

Answer (score 1):

The point was that I had a relay chain and a parachain on the same server, and such as the default prometheus port - 9615 on the relay chain and I set ports 9615 and 9616 on the parachain, the relay chain metrics simply overlapped the metrics of the parachain itself, as a result, I changed prometheus relay chain port to 9715 and it worked